# The database disk image is malformed sqlite

Tags: .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have migrated my `.net 2.0` projects to `.net 4.0`.
With this I had to upgrade `system.data.sqlite` libraries to the latest versions available `1.0.81`.

Right now when I try to query large tables using `select * from table` I get **`The database disk image is malformed`** error. This only happens on tables with lots of records, small tables return records.

Please note if I go back to `.net 2.0` and `system.data.sqlite 1.0.66` the same DB file works perfecly.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I just downloaded and started using 1.0.82.
This new version it debug prints the errors on the VS2010.(nice).

So the error is actually
SQLite error (11): database corruption at line 49537 of [c0d89d4a97]

So i guess the DB is corrupted.

How come 1.0.66 reads the DB and newer versions dont ?
strange!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i done some tests and found out that actually its just a little operation that resolves it.

1. open db with any software
2. remove db password
3. save db
4. open db
5. set password again

pretty stupid.

hope this helps any body that is stuck with same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Also encountered a similar problem recently. Even after updating all AColumn values in ATable table to a new value e.g 2 using the following query

```
UPDATE ATable SET AColumn = 2;
```

the following select distinct query

```
SELECT DISTINCT AColumn from ATable;
```

returned old values e.g. 1,2,3, and

```
SELECT * FROM ATable WHERE AColumn = 1
```

resulted in a **"The database disk image is malformed sqlite"**  error.

ATable had an index on AColumn and all the queries going through that index returned wrong result. Running integrity check using the following PRAGMA proved that some indexes were corrupt.

```
PRAGMA integrity_check;
```

IDX_AColumn was missing a lot of rows and the index also contained wrong number of entries. Luckily data in all the tables was intact, only a few indexes were corrupt. Reindexing the corrupt indexes solved problem.

```
REINDEX ATable; http://www.sqlite.org/lang_reindex.html
```

If a lot of indexes are corrupt you can reindex all of then at the same time using command:

```
REINDEX;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your database file *is* corrupted, the older SQLite version just doesn't detect this.

Create a new database file with data from your backup (or with as much data as you can scrape out of the old DB).